# Ошибка "ORA-00904", "ORA-06512" при вызове хранимой процедуры

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

Привет всем! Короче есть созданная процедура ppp, которая создает таблицу! При вызове процедуры со входным данным varchar2. Выводит ошибки: ORA-00904, ORA-06512! Где ошибка? Прошу помочь!!!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код создания процедуры:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ppp(poz in varchar2) is
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
  'create table tmp#ppp_'||poz||' as
  select * 
  from  tmp#players_1 
  where pl_pos = ' || poz ;
END ppp;
```

Код вызова процедуры:

`call ppp('MF');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы потеряли кавычки вокруг `MF`. и в результате Оракл пытался выполнить такой запрос:

```
create table tmp#ppp_MF as
   select * 
   from tmp#players_1 
   where pl_pos = MF
```

Очевидно, что колонки `MF` у Вас нет. Перепишите процедуру вот так:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ppp(poz in varchar2) is
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
   'create table tmp#ppp_'||poz||' as
   select * 
   from tmp#players_1 
   where pl_pos = ''' || poz||'''' ;
END ppp;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Правильно!